# SQL Server Service Accounts Max Character Length

Tags: sql-server, service-accounts

I've been considering a new naming convention for all SQL Server service accounts for instances in our enterprise.  I ran into some issues on my lab environment.

Is there a character limit to SQL Server service account names?

```
DOMAIN\SQL-Service-COMPUTER-NAME
DOMAIN\SQL-Agent-COMPUTER-NAME
DOMAIN\SQL-SSRS-COMPUTER-NAME
DOMAIN\SQL-SSAS-COMPUTER-NAME
DOMAIN\SQL-SSIS-COMPUTER-NAME
```

Answer (score 1):

Within SQL Server, the datatype for the name column in [`sys.database_principles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-principals-transact-sql) is `sysname`, which is essentially `nvarchar(128)`. However, the [`sAMAccountName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/naming-properties#samaccountname) attribute in Active Directory specifies the login name must be 20 or fewer characters.

A similar question was posted within the forums on SQLServerCentral:

> https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/max-length-of-ad-names-for-security